# Qt. Making a QGraphicsItem follow cursor at all times

Tags: c++, qt

I wish to make a custom graphics item to follow the cursor without needing to be clicked on. My view has `setMouseTracking(true)`, my graphics item has `setFlag(ItemIsMovable, true); setAcceptHoverEvents(true);`, but it doesn't track the cursor, I have to click and drag it. What is the proper way to make a `QGraphicsItem` follow the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only capture mouse event on an item if your cursor pass above it. For example, instead of clicking on the item, you can react on mouseMove events.

But you seem to want a more global behaviour. You could track `mouseMoveEvent` directly on your QGraphicsView (or on your QGraphicsScene if you have multiple views) (see [mouseMoveEvent](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#mouseMoveEvent)). After that, just keep a reference on your item and make it move each time you intercept an event